# Как передать аутентифицированного юзера в провайдер Laravel

Tags: laravel

```
$this->app->bind(UploadService::class, function() {
    return new UploadService(Auth::user());
});
```

Хотелось что бы в `UploadService` попадал аутентифицированный юзер, но все время получаю null. Данного юзера планирую использовать в сервисе обработки фото. Или есть еще какие нибудь варианты получения юзера?

Comment: Чем Вас не устраивает вызов `auth()->user()` (с ошибкой при неаутентифицированном пользователе) или `request()->user()` (без ошибки) откуда угодно?

Comment: Не устраивает тем что оба варианта null) Но спасибо, с помощью request()->request->get('user') получилось достучаться до id юзера

Comment: Ну вообще странно, по идее должно отдавать пользователя, если он действительно вошёл. Ну или сервис регистрируется до Auth